# show images in view, using viewmodel

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, view, viewmodel

Good day, how are you? 
I am currently working with mvc,c#,sql and I am doing this:
I have a viewmodel like this:

```
 public class htmlviewmodel
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public string style { get; set; }
}
```

and I am trying to get an image url and show the image in my view, the url comes from my database

```
  entity db = new myentity();
  var html = new htmlviewmodel();
  html.body="<img src=&quot;"+db.getmyimageurl().tostring()+";&quot; > ";
```

My view would be like the following:

```
<div> my image: @Model.html.body  </div>
```

but it doesnot show the image, instead it shows a string like this

```
<img src=&quot;imageUrlNotworking....//...;&quot; > "
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? how can I fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `;&quot;` doesn't need `;` at beginning , instead of `&quot;` you can use `\"` or `'`(single quot).
After that you must decode html first then use `Html.Raw` method to render your html:

```
<div> my image: @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.html.body))  </div>
```

or convert your string to HtmlString like this:

```
@{ var htmlBody= new HtmlString(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.html.body));}
 <div> my image: @htmlBody  </div>
```

Comment: thank you! it worked! one more question, what about if I want to pass html from my database? for instance, a table ?how should I proceed?

Comment: @EbaneoVk , if you want to save your HTML inside database you should use HtmlEncode method to encode HTML first, and show it on view using HtmlDecode and Html.Raw methods

Answer (score 0):

If you store image url in database its store like "c:\picture.png." but you actually need "c:/picture.png". so convert '\' to this '/'. I face it previous like this.

Comment: your code seems like it come from db...debug your code